# Fire JQUERY function more than once using the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 divisions in the html code and after the first division a button "show more" has been placed. I want to fire a jquery command which shows the second division on clicking the button "show more" once and the third division on again clicking the button and so on.

The problem is that i am only able to show the second division and not able to fire the jquery script the second time to show the third division.

below is my Jquery and html.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i=2;i<=5;i++)
  {
   $("#"+i).hide();
  }
  i=2; /* degrade the value of i */

  $("button").on("click",function(){
   //alert(i);
   $("#button").remove();
   $("#"+i).show();
   var button="<button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show  more</button>";
   $("#"+i).after(button);
   i=i+1;
  });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="1" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="2" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="3" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="4" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="5" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
 
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: Why are you destroying your button, then trying to re-create it immediately after? Just use the same button. Otherwise you'll need delegation for dynamically added elements.

Comment: i am removing and recreating my button so that the "show more" option remains at the bottom of the page and the new division is placed before or above the button.

Comment: @rishabhjain The way I have approached is much better compared to yours. Would that work by any chance or do you have any restrictions?

Comment: @rishabb Just place your button _after_ the hidden elements??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I guess a very short and clean solution is this: https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/h6huonub/1/

Use the detach() function to handle the button. This way you DO NOT lose the event delegation of the button and it is way less resource intensive.

The key part is this line:

```
var el = $('#button').detach();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i=2;i<=5;i++)
  {
   $("#"+i).hide();
  }
  i=2;

  $("button").on("click",function(){

            var el = $('#button').detach();
            
   $("#"+i).show();
   $("#"+i).after(el);
   i=i+1;
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="1" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="2" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="3" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="4" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="5" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
 
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

**EDIT:** Added working code snippet.

Comment: Nice solution. Almost the same as mine, only making the detaching and reinserting explicit. I'd upvote your answer if you'd include your code as a snippet. This'll help preserve the answer in case JSFiddle would go down in the future.

Comment: There you go ;-)

Comment: There *you* go ;-)

Comment: This is the sweetest and shortest solution. Sir! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this way. The trick is:

```
$(":hidden").first().show()
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("p:not(:first)").hide();
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("p:hidden").first().show();
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; line-height: 1;}
p {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<a href="#">Show</a>
```

Also, you can add one more check to find if there are any more hidden `<p>` and then you can remove the link too:

```js
$(function () {
  $("p:not(:first)").hide();
  $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("p:hidden").first().show();
    if (!$("p:hidden").length)
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; line-height: 1;}
p {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
<p>Paragraph 5</p>
<a href="#">Show</a>
```

Comment: Would only suggest to be more specific about selector

Comment: @Raimonds Sorry, didn't understand. Can you please kindly clarify?

Comment: Your main trick here is that you put the show button all the way at the end. You should clarify that in your answer. Not sure if that works for OP, but it's definitely a nice approach.

Comment: $(":hidden").first().show(), I skipped snippet code and just checked how it is working, what I was trying to say for that code to scale better you should isolate that logic from rest of the page, like have parent container with id, and target only specific paragraphs for hidden, as It might become a huge pain onwards

Comment: @Justastudent Yup... Just commented that to OP. Let's see what he's upto.

Comment: @Raimonds This is [mcve]. `:)` In other words, a pseudo snippet. No one should directly blindly copy things.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Nice solution, but I would just stick with the detach() function like I mentioned in my answer. This way you do not have to deal with compoarisons for hidden elements and stuff. Have a look, what do you think? https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/h6huonub/1/

Comment: @hallleron Very much agree. I see the problem and derive the solution. So I thought of suggesting this way. I should have started by saying, if I were you... So... I would do this way...

Comment: Thank you. This one is profound and a little bit advanced for a Rookie.

Comment: @rishabhjain Welcome, but I feel the accepted answer is complicated for me. Different people different views. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It's because your second button is not in the DOM when you initialize your function.

Instead use this:

```
    $('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
       // Your code
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i=2;i<=5;i++)
  {
   $("#"+i).hide();
  }
  i=2; /* degrade the value of i */

  $("body").on("click", "button" ,function(){
   //alert(i);
   $("#button").remove();
   $("#"+i).show();
   var button="<button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show  more</button>";
   $("#"+i).after(button);
   i=i+1;
  });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="1" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="2" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="3" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="4" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="5" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
 
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: I'd like to know why this has been downvoted, because event delegation is one way to solve the problem

Comment: I'm curious to know it too because this is working with a simple modification :-)

Comment: @Jeremy It was downvoted when the answer did not include the snippet, maybe that's why? Downvotes are random sometimes, I've given up on trying to understand them. One downvote is already retracted.

Comment: I thought my answer was clear enough without a snippet

Comment: Silent downvoters are a pain and don't bring anything. We should always say _why_ we downvote, so people can understand their mistakes and get better. For that matter, I think Stackoverflow should force downvoters to write a justification.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you destroying your button, then trying to re-create it immediately after? Just use the same button. Otherwise you'll need delegation for dynamically added elements.

```
$("#button").click( () => $(`#${++i}`).show())
```

Or in ES5:

```
$("#button").click( function(){ $("#" + (++i) }).show())
```

You say that you're destroying the button and re-creating it so it's always after the last shown element, well, place the button directly after all hidden elements and leave it here...

Comment: Uh! ES6. I don't know when I am gonna master this art... `:(`

Comment: Are you kidding? Basically it's replacing `function(){}` with `() => {}`

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the button and insert a new one, it does not have your click handler attached to it. What you can do instead is *move* the existing button, which will retain the click handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i, $button = $('#button');
  for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    $("#" + i).hide();
  }
  i = 2; /* degrade the value of i */

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var $i = $("#" + i);
    $button.insertAfter($i);
    $i.show();
    i = i + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="1" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    <button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="2" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="3" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="4" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="5" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>

  </div>
  <!-- .row -->
</div>
<!-- .container -->
```

Indeed, the documentation of [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) mentions that

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be **moved** after the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned:

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="ID_1" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
            <button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>


      </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->

<!-- end snippet -->

<script>

    var id=1;
        $(document).ready(function(){

                $("body").on("click", "button" ,function(){
                id++;

                var div='<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="ID_'+id+'" style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:300px;"></div>';
                    var button="<button id='button' class='btn btn-primary'>show more</button>";
                $("#button").remove();
                $(".row").append(div);
                    $(".row").append(button);
                });
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
        $("#" + i).hide();
    }
    var i = 2; /* degrade the value of i */

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("#" + i).show();
        i = i + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: 1) The click handler is outside the `document.ready` so it won't work. 2) The dynamically added button still won't have any click event attached to it so it won't work... Downvoted